# Implemente um programa em C que apresente a QUANTIDADE de números primos presentes em um vetor, utilizando alocação dinâmica de vetores

Tags: c

estou montando um programinha que tem como objetivo contar quantos números primos tem presentes em um vetor e dizer ao usuário a quantia. Neste caso, se o vetor tiver 5 números primos, o programa deverá imprimir o numero 5.

```
int primos(int n, int* vet)
{
    int i, prim;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(i = 2; i <= vet[i]/2; i++){
            if(vet[i]%i==0){
            prim++;
          }
       }
    }
    return(prim);
}


int main()
{

    int i, n, prim;

    printf("Digite o Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int* vet = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        if(vet == NULL){
            printf("Erro de alocação!");
            exit(1);
        }
    printf("Digite os elementos do vetor: ");
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
        }
        prim = primos(n, vet);
    printf("O vetor tem %d Numero(s) primo(s).", prim);
    free(vet); return 0;
}
```

Eu estou com uma dificuldade nesse programa, teriam como me ajudar a completar ele?

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade, implementar alguma lógica, ou consertar um problema? É erro de compilação? Erro em tempo de execução? Resultado diferente do esperado? Descreva o que você precisa.

Comment: Eu queria dicas de como fazer ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiquei os seguintes erros no seu programa:

- A variável `prim` não é inicializada (`prim = 0`) dentro da função `primos()`.
- Está sendo utilizada uma mesma variável chamada `i` para os dois `for()` aninhados dentro da função `primos()`, fazendo com que um `for` altere a variável do outro.
- Seu loop `for` interno na função `primos()` incrementa a variável `prim` exatamente quando o número é divisível por `i` (`vet[i] % i == 0`). Tem de ser o contrário, o número só será primo se não for divisível por nenhum `i`.
- Creio que você já tenha feito isso, mas é preciso incluir as bibliotecas `stdio.h` e `stdlib.h`

Algumas considerações que não afetam o funcionamento do programa, mas podem lhe ajudar:

- Quando não forem necessárias fora do loop, as variáveis temporárias utilizadas para iteração nos loops `for` podem ser declaradas e inicializadas diretamente dentro da cláusula `for`  [ex. `for(int i, i < 10; ++i){;}`].
- Você pode chamar a função `primos()` diretamente de dentro do `printf()`.
- Compile seus programas preferencialmente com a flag `-Wall` e
  eventualmente `-pedantic` (`gcc -Wall -pedantic primos.c -o primos`). Isso lhe ajudará a identificar erros.

A seguir a versão que fiz do programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int primos(int n, int* vet)
{
    int prim = 0, j;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 2; j <= vet[i]/2; j++)
            if(vet[i] % j == 0)
                break;

        if (j == vet[i]/2 + 1)
            prim++;
    }

    return(prim);
}


int main()
{

    int n;

    printf("Digite o Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int* vet = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if(vet == NULL)
    {
            printf("Erro de alocação!");
            exit(1);
    }

    printf("Digite os elementos do vetor:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            printf("Elemento %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }

    printf("O vetor tem %d Numero(s) primo(s).", primos(n, vet));

    free(vet); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda !!